# Terraform script

Tags: shell, terraform

Created an EC2 instance using terraform,now I want to modify the instance type without manual intervention. automatically it should change using wrapper script.

Example I launched an AWS ec2 instance using terraform with basic configuration like instance type,number of instance like that. But when I want to change instances count from one to 2 Or to change any configuration I'm doing manually by editing the terraform code .

1. I wanted to automate that phase by wrappr script

Main.tf

> terraform {
> required_providers {
> aws = {
> source = "hashicorp/aws"
> }
> }
> resource "aws_instance" "" {
> ami           = var.ami
> instance_type = var.instance_type
>
> network_interface {
> network_interface_id = var.network_interface_id
> device_index         = 0
> }
> credit_specification {
> cpu_credits = "unlimited"
> }
> }

> Var.tf

> variable "network_interface_id" {
> type = string
> default = "network_id_from_aws"
> }
>
> variable "ami" {
> type = string
> default = "ami-005e54dee72cc1d00"
> }
>
> variable "instance_type" {
> type = string
> default = "t2.micro"
> }

Here I wanted to modify "instance type" t2. Micro to t2.large.
automatically withoutght manually going inside var.tf file

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly:

You want to have a Terraform script that you don't want to change even when you want to change some stuff in your infrastructure like Instances count, machine type, etc.

For this use case, you can simply provide values for your variables either from the Terraform plan/apply, by creating custom *.tfvars files, or by using `TF_VAR_*` environment variable (see more at: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#variable-definition-precedence).

So for example, for a script like the following:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }
}
resource "aws_instance" "myinstance" {
  count         = var.instance_count
  ami           = var.ami
  instance_type = var.instance_type

  network_interface {
    network_interface_id = var.network_interface_id
    device_index         = 0
  }

  credit_specification {
    cpu_credits = "unlimited"
  }
}

# Var.tf
variable "network_interface_id" {
  type    = string
  default = "network_id_from_aws"
}

variable "ami" {
  type    = string
  default = "ami-005e54dee72cc1d00"
}

variable "instance_type" {
  type    = string
  default = "t2.micro"
}

variable "instance_count" {
  type   = number
  defult = 1
}
```

I would add this line to my wrapper script (let's say it's a bash script running from my CI pipeline)

```
terraform plan -var instance_count=2 -var instance_type=t2.large
```

or, I would create a `*.tfvars` file on the fly from my script inputs

---

However, if you want to do more than that, consider that Terraform is an IaaC technology. You may want to have Terraform scripts as close as possible to the reality (what you have on your cloud environment).